# reReport moved from OBIEE11g to OBIEE 12c not shown up in Catalog

Tags: report, obiee, catalog

I have a report in OBIEE11. I moved the report directory to OBIEE12c. The Report is not shown up in OBIEE 12c's Catalog. What could be the issue ?

Comment: "moved it" - how? And from which exact "11" to wich exact "12"?

Comment: Moved the report directory from 11g to 12c .

Comment: How? What does that mean "moved the report directly"? Also: "report"?! So you are talking about BI Publisher because OBI uses "analyses" and not "reports". Those two are technically two completely different object types-

Comment: To clarify: "move" can mean "move via file system" ; "move via archive / unarchive" etc...

Comment: In OBIEE 11g when a report is created all the metadata of report including datamodel .. are stored in a directory. I moved this directly to repository of OBIEE 12g.

Comment: When installing OBIEE 12c, if we select BI Enterprise Edition during confuguration....Catalog type is not shown as FileSystem. So we are not seeing the Catalog objects copied to 12C.  And there is no option to change to File System.

Comment: Geez....which "12c"? There are almost 20 releases so far

Comment: Its 12.2.1.2.0.

Comment: Last update from me on this because despite numerous attempts to get a statement that makes any sense...it still does not. Please try at least to learn the proper words to describe things since "all the metadata of report including datamodel .. are stored in a directory. I moved this directly to repository of OBIEE 12g." makes as much sense as saying "I moved the passengers into the engine of the car". And: "And there is no option to change to File System." clearly show that you have yet to understand how the product works at its core.

Comment: I can't train you over SO and if you can't state properly what the issue is I can't help you.

Comment: I copied the report directory from OBIEE 11g repository in its files system and pasted it in OBIEE12c repository.

Answer (score 1):

File system copies are not the supported way to do this. Archive / unarchive is supported and the correct way to do things.

Comment: It was working between OBIEE versions of 10g and 11g. Is anything changed with 12c ?

Comment: If you read the documentation the you will see that you must be on a high patch level of 11.1.1.7 or 11.1.1.9 for it to work. Also you have to look at other changes that an upgrade can bring like renaming default app roles.